# Analysing a genotypic 2X2 table instead of a 3X2 table

Tags: case-control-study, test-for-trend

This could be a simple question to seasoned statistical genetics folks. I have delved into this doing an analysis for a friend on the sideline of a bioinformatics task I was helping her with. An opportunity for me to learn new things.

For context: I have a table of genotype frequencies for cases and healthy controls across different ethnicities. My hypothesis is that a disease severity is associated with the genotype. That is, a mutation from GG to GA or AA might increase the severity of the disease.

I identified few tests for trends that are interesting to my question: The Cochran-Armitage trend test and the chi-square test to explore the independence of the genotypes.

Specifically, I like to stand corrected/criticized/advised on my analysis strategy. Can the R function prop.trend.test() be used for the same purpose as CA test if I have a 2X2 genotype table (not allele) instead of a 3X2 table ?

So for gentoypes GG (case=41, control=29), GA (n=1,2) and AA (n=0,2). I want to see whether there exists a trend associated with the AA homozygote only, I can do a 2X2 table as follows:

```
          Control    Case  RowTotals
AA         0          2      2
GA+GG      42         31     73
colTotals  42         33     75
```

Then do prop.trend.test(c(2,31),c(2,73)) using the row totals.

Similarly If I want to see whether the allele A involvement shows a trend I can modify the table as follows and do prop.trend.test(c(29,4),c(70,5)):

```
          Control    Case  RowTotals
GG         41         29     70
GA+AA      1          4       5 
colTotals  42         33     75
```

The genotypes in cases and controls are in Hardy-Weinberg equilibrium. The disease I am testing has a low prevalence, I do not know if the disease is multiplicative and therefore I am using genotypes instead of allele frequencies, I read that from a paper suggesting these three assumptions have to hold for working with allelic counts. Also my sample size is too small consisting only of 34 cases and 41 controls.

Does my idea make sense?

Comment: Did you try my method of prop.trend.test mentioned in answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 41, 1 and 0 cases out of a total of 70, 3 and 2 subjects for GG, AG and AA, respectively, prop.trend.test may be done as follows:

```
> prop.trend.test(c(41,1,0), c(70,3,2))

        Chi-squared Test for Trend in Proportions

data:  c(41, 1, 0) out of c(70, 3, 2) ,
 using scores: 1 2 3
X-squared = 3.3444, df = 1, p-value = 0.06743
```

It shows that there is a trend towards significant association of reducing risk of disease with A allele, since proportion of cases are reducing from GG to AG to AA (from 59% to 33% to 0%).

Edit: As discussed in comments, Cochran-Armitage test is the preferred test for this situation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Armitage_test_for_trend#Application_to_genetics)

```
> CA_df<-data.frame(case=c(41,1,0), control=c(29,2,2)) 
> independence_test(control ~ case, data=CA_df)

        Asymptotic General Independence Test

data:  control by case
Z = 1.4139, p-value = 0.1574
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

One should also be able to do it after combining A allele groups:

```
> CA_df<-data.frame(case=c(41,1), control=c(29,4)) 
> independence_test(control ~ case, data=CA_df)

        Asymptotic General Independence Test

data:  control by case
Z = 1, p-value = 0.3173
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

Comment: Thanks, I used prop.trend.test() that way which works well. I wanted to take a step further and learn about the  legitimacy of modifying the tables to 2X2 to emphasize the AA genotype trend in cases as well as the combined AA/GA trend in cases against the backdrop of the WT GG.

Comment: The result I get from prop.trend.test() is significantly different in comparison to what I get from Cochrane-Armitage test which is mind boggling. How can that be explained. Here is my code

      `library(coin)
      CA_df<-data.frame(case=c(41,1,0), control=c(29,2,2))
      independence_test(control ~ case, data=CA_df)`

Comment: I agree Cochran-Armitage test should be done. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Armitage_test_for_trend#Application_to_genetics I have edited my answer.